# In linux, how to install pytesseract for python 2.7, not for python 3?

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'd like to install pytesseract in python2.7/dist-packages.
I tried "pip install pytesseract".
But it is installed in python3/dist-packages.
Please help me.

Comment: Your `pip` is apparently the Python 3 one. There is no single universal Linux solution to this, it depends on your distro etc. The absolutely simplest workaround in to use a virtualenv.

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is a small script that executes the pip package. You can do that yourself with the python of your choice using the `-m` option. Assuming your python 2.7 executable is `python`, you can

```
python -m pip install pytesseract
```

or

```
sudo -H python -m pip install pytesseract
```

if you want to install into system directories.